# Using Feeds, how to import D7 files and images into a D8 media field

Tags: 8, media, feeds

Looking for a method for importing D7 files and images with multiple values into a D8 media field. Any recommendations out there?

The [official Feeds issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/2928904) doesn't have much activity and seems to have strayed off-topic.

[Feeds Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_migrate) module is not stable and not recommended for use in production.

I have also tried a module called [Media Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_feeds) but ran into problem with multiple value fields.

Upgrading to Drupal 8 using core's Migrate Drupal module is not suitable because I only want to import data belonging to a single content type.

I don't do much code so would prefer to avoid the Migrate route.

Can anyone provide a site builder method for getting this done?

Comment: What got you stuck? Why can't you just export the D7 values into a CSV for example, and create an importer for it on D8?

Comment: This is one approach I have tried extensively. It seem that Feeds does not yet have an importer for media fields.

Comment: Does this help? [Importing files and media](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/feeds/importing-files-and-media)

Comment: Thank you @prkos. I got there in the end. Currently, Feeds does not support this in one step. It is necessary to first import images into a media entity and second, to reference the new media entities to the node's media field.